# Recompiling of c++ Source Files in a Project After Changing a Function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation

In Visual C++, if I change what a function, class, struct, etc. does in a source file but not the corresponding prototype in its header file, will all source files that use the function, class, struct, etc. need to be recompiled?

For instance, if I initially have something like this:

```
//function.h
int function(int x, int y);

//function.cpp
int function(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

//main.cpp
#include function.h

int main(){
    int x=3
    int y=2
    std::cout<<function(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

And then I change function.cpp to this:

```
//function.cpp
int function(int x, int y){
    return x*y;
}
```

Will I need to recompile main.cpp?

Comment: it depends on how smart visual studio's dependency management is; why don't you try it out?

Comment: You also try out SCONS, Gradle et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to recompile main, because the [ABI (Application Binary Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of your function didn't change. However, you need to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) your main application against the recompiled function.cpp.

Comment: So if I just have a Visual Studio project, will it automatically link them when I recompile the project?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Usually yes.

Comment: As long as you do a "Build" Visual Studio cares automatically about which files need to be (re)compiled / linked. Only if you do a "Rebuild" all source files will be recompiled.